# Gvim - Change window position horizontally

Tags: gvim, functions, variables

I want to create a command that will place my gvim window to a different "x" location on my screen while maintaining the "y" position.

I do this in my _gvimrc by calling

```
winpos 319 16
```

I want to create a function `WinRight` that will put my window on the right side of the screen, but this doesn't work:

```
function! WinRight()
    let ypos=getwinposy()
    winpos 1241 ypos
endfunction
```

When I `:call WinRight()`, I get "E466 :winpos requires two number arguments".

The function works if I substitute a number for `ypos`.  Why doesn't my use of the variable `ypos` work here though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) to assemble a command from a string, which allows you to include the contents of a variable or return value from a function.

This should work:

```
function! WinRight()
    let ypos=getwinposy()
    execute "winpos 1241 ".ypos
endfunction
```

Or even:

```
function! WinRight()
    execute "winpos 1241 ".getwinposy()
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to create a command that will place my gvim window to a different "x" location on my screen while maintaining the "y" position.*

As a more general solution to the problem of rearranging windows, you might look at Divvy – it's a window manager available on [Mac](https://mizage.com/divvy/) and [Windows](https://mizage.com/windivvy/) (there are probably other options for both of those operating systems, or Linux).

Using Divvy, you get to define global keyboard commands that allow you to move any window from any application to one of several specific screen regions. I have defined `cmd-ctrl-8` (as a chord) to relocate the current window to the left half of the screen, `cmd-ctrl-9` to the right half, and `cmd-ctrl-0` to maximize to full screen. I use it to rearrange vim windows as well as everything else – terminals, browser, email, etc.

I don't know how many it supports in total, I have 9 unique shortcut/locations defined and it still shows the "New" button to create another one.